# Join Game over VPN

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I have multiple iOS devices in one city and one iOS device in another city. I'd like to play Minecraft Pocket Edition with the other device but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here are some more details:

- All devices are iOS, all with the latest OS at the time of this writing (6.1.2), and all using the latest MCPE at the time of this writing (0.6.1 alpha)
- No devices are jailbroken and this isn't possible in my scenario
- All devices have Server Visible by Default enabled
- All of the local devices are behind a single Wi-Fi router and have play MCPE together before
- The LAN is on a Linksys WRT54GS wireless router
- I also have at my disposal a Windows 7 Home Pro laptop

From what I read and watched, this was possible at some point, but all examples I saw were *limited to MCPE v0.3*. I have configured successfully the Windows box to act as a VPN server (using Windows 7's built-in VPN feature); a 4G iOS device was able to connect to the VPN and visit an intranet website on my home LAN. But, when a local iOS device has MCPE started and a map in play, the 4G-connected device cannot see it in the Join Game screen.

I'm experienced as a web developer but not really experienced as a multiplayer gamer; I think I could handle the technical setup stuff but there may be an obvious gaming thing I overlooked (like some UDP nuance, or port added to the router forwarding or something).

*Is what I'm trying to do even possible? What am I missing, or am I even on the right track?*

Comment: Are you *sure* the device using 4G was accessing the LAN website through VPN? VPN is a networking tech that each device has to implement itself, or it has to be getting network access from a gateway that is itself routing over VPN software. Your mobile provider's 4G is most certainly not going to route to a private VPN without extraordinary measures on your part (probably involving jail breaking).

Comment: I was able to browse to my printer's config page, http://192.168.1.11 (i.e. private network IP); Wi-Fi was turned off and I was using the VPN configuration under Settings > General > VPN. The Send All Traffic checkbox was On so I think that is how it was doing it. I also confirmed at the time that the server listed one client as connected.

Comment: Cool, that eliminates that possible problem. (And I learned that Apple has built-in VPN support now!) And was the local iOS device also showing up as a VPN client?

Comment: No, I did not have the local device connected over VPN. I was, uh, hoping it would all work out b/c the VPN server and local iOS device were on the same LAN? :) Do I need to share or bridge-connect the adapter, or all connect to the same VPN, or something?